# Always require email signature when attempting to send email in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-signature

Up until today, my company's policy with regards to email signatures was one signature for all emails - new, replies, internal, external/client-facing.  Today, they rolled out a new policy with signatures.  Starting today, there's one signature for internal emails, a different signature for external/client-facing emails and a different signature for replies.  Giving this policy change, I can no longer have a "default" signature configured in Outlook.

Since I can no longer have a "default" signature, how do I force Microsoft Outlook to prompt me for a signature everytime I try to send an email either by clicking the Send button or using the keyboard combination, CTRL+S?

I'm running Microsoft Outlook 2013 (15.0.4893.1000) 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option as far as I know. However, a little trick might make your life easier. If I understand correctly, you have a total of four cases:

1. new email - internal
2. new email - external
3. reply - internal
4. reply - external

What I would do is create two default signatures, one for new emails and one for replies, each containing what you would write for internal emails **and** what you would write for external emails. Then, set them as defaults for new emails and replies, respectively. On message creation, all you would need to do is delete the non-relevant lines from your signature. This is even simpler to do than select a different signature from a hypothetical prompt.